# Annotate and aggreagate mixed in django query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two tables called `Image` and `Product`.

```
class Image():
     product = Foreignkey(Product, related_name='image')
     #some more field e.g. image_name, slug, caption, etc.
```

A product can have ZERO, One or at max 5 images.
I want to calculate the count of products which have X no. of images.

I tried with naive approach but its doing N(#products)+1 SQL queries.

```
d = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
for x in product.objects.all():
    d[x.image.count()] += 1
```

I think we can do it using `select_related` but not sure how to do it.
I tried to do with annotate but not working. 
`Image.objects.annotate(x=Count('product'))`
I'm not very my much experience in django. I want to know If I can do it  in a single query or more optimize way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a group by having sql query. In django orm you can search "Filtering on annotations" from django doc.

```
Product.objects.annotate(num_images=Count('image')).filter(num_images=5)
```